# Как написать несколько циклов в цикле на R?

Tags: циклы, r

Есть таблица: [image: Где есть фильтры L0, L1, L2, L3, L4, pasp1-pasp7. И значения v0001-v0005]
В таблице 85 столбцов и более миллиона строк.
Надо посчитать все вариации: Столько v0001[v0001==1] при всех значениях фильтров фильтры L0, L1, L2, L3, L4, pasp1-pasp7.

Если идти в лоб через циклы

```
`for(i in 1:5){
  for (k in 1:5) {
  x[i,k]= length(df$v0001[df$v0001==i & df$pasp1==k])
}}
`
```

То жизни не хватит посчитать.

Пример: образа  [image: результата в excel]

Как посчитать быстрее ?

Comment: вам же группировка данных нужна. вот её и используйте. // ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста: [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Правильно ли я понял, что необходимо посчитать число Только единиц?
(Если да, то sapply и subset должны помочь (в т.ч. облегчив датафрейм, убрав оттуда строки, где ни одно из значений !=0).

Если необходимо посчитать Вообще все, то, возможно, поможет преобразование в tidy формат (https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html).

Боюсь, для более точного ответа необходимо больше данных.